# Spring JPA count where group by

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to transform a sql query in JPA.

```
SELECT status, count(*)
FROM abc
WHERE type='XXX'
GROUP BY status
```

I need something in a JPARepository with sql.

```
@Repository
public interface ABCRepository extends JpaRepository<abc, Long> {

   long countByStatusAndType(final A type, final B status);
}
```

Is it Possible?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, create class containing parameters `status` and `count` for handling results, then create method in repository with query

```
@Query("SELECT status, count(*) as count FROM abc WHERE type=:type GROUP BY status")
List<CustomResultClass> countByStatus(String type);
```